# How to map Key Value pair from one map onto another

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

If I have a map with the following data:

```
"a", "hello"
"b", "bye"
"c", "good morning"
```

and a second map with the following data:

```
"key1","a"
"key2", "b"
"key3", "c"
```

is it then possible to perform an operation such that I can map the value of my second map onto the key as my first map? Which would result in the final map looking like this:

```
"key1","hello"
"key2", "bye"
"key3", "good morning"
```

Comment: `fistMap.get(secondMap.get("key1"))` will return `"hello"` - is that what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you want a third map made of keys from the second map, and matching values from the first map.

```java
Map< String , String > thirdMap = new HashMap<>() ;
for ( Map.Entry< String , String > entry : secondMap.entrySet() ) {
    thirdMap.put(
        entry.getKey() ,                  // Second map’s key.
        firstMap.get( entry.getValue() )  // First map’s value.
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant  firstMap.get( entry.getValue() )  // First map’s value.

Comment: @Yusuf'Seed'Seedat Yes, my mistake there. Now fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The below code should work, for what you are trying to do

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, String> keyToValue = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("a", "hello");
        put("b", "bye");
        put("c", "good morning");
    }};
    HashMap<String, String> keyToSecondaryKey = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("key1", "a");
        put("key2", "b");
        put("key3", "c");
    }};

    keyToSecondaryKey.entrySet().forEach(e-> {
        e.setValue(keyToValue.get(e.getValue()));
    });

    System.out.println(keyToSecondaryKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this way:

```java
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("a", "hello");
map1.put("b", "bye");
map1.put("c", "good morning");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("key1", "a");
map2.put("key2", "b");
map2.put("key3", "c");

map2.forEach((key2, value2) -> map2.put(key2, map1.get(value2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you.  Note that this creates a third map.

```
Map<String, String> map1 =
        Map.of("a", "hello", "b", "bye", "c", "good morning");

Map<String, String> map2 =
        Map.of("key1", "a", "key2", "b", "key3", "c");
```

- Stream the entry set of `map2`
- Use that `entry's key` as the key to the result map
- use that  `entry's value` as the key to retrieve the value of `map1`

```
Map<String, String> result = map2.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                e->map1.get(e.getValue())));
        
result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
key1=hello
key2=bye
key3=good morning
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in the comment the statement below will print `"hello"`. And there's no need to do create a **third map** if you want to access the content of these two maps right in the same code.

```
System.out.println(fistMap.get(secondMap.get("key1")));
```

With the following code, you can iterate print the **keys** of the second map and the **values** of the first map (with the assumption that *all* values of the second map are present in the first map as keys).

```
fistMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + secondMap.get(v)));
```

And only if you need to pass the data from these two maps to another part of your application it might make sense to create the third combined map. It could be done with the **Stream IPA** like that:

```
Map<String, String> combinedMap = 
       secondMap.keySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), // key of the new map
                                      k -> fistMap.get(secondMap.get(k)))); // value of the new map
```